# SQL Sum Over Partition Order by

Tags: sql, sum

I am using below query in SQL and it is giving an error saying

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

I want to get cumulative value for the column increment_inch. This column value should change as Device changes.

Can you anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
SELECT TSI.INCREMENT_SEQ_NUM as STRAPPING,
       TSI.INCREMENT_INCH as #_of_INCREMENTS,
       TSI.VOLUME_BBL as FACTOR_PER_INCREMENT,
       SUM(increment_inch) OVER (PARTITION BY ts.master_device_id ORDER BY TSI.INCREMENT_SEQ_NUM) AS CUMULATIVE_INCREMENTS
FROM TANK_STRAPPING TS INNER JOIN  
     TANK_STRAPPING_INCREMENT TSI
     ON TS.STRAPPING_ID = TSI.STRAPPING_ID
```

Comment: This query is working fine.

Comment: What's your DBMS, does it support Cumulative Sums? E.g. older versions of SQL Server only supported Group Sums...

Comment: What's the database? Some accept windowing functions, others don't.